# Why does Google Maps containsLocation never find a point inside my polygon?

Tags: google-maps, google-maps-api-3

I'm having issues with the following code in that my points never find a point within a polygon using google.maps.geometry.poly.containsLocation.  You can see the full code and that there are indeed points in the polygon here http://htinteractive.com/crime_map_fairview.html  However in the console you will see that none of the points were found to be in the polygon per the containsLocation function.

I feel like maybe I'm not passing in one the values correctly to the containsLocation function, but so far what I've found in the documentation this seems correct.

```
var myLatlng = new google.maps.LatLng(lat,lon);
        fairview = [
            new google.maps.LatLng(39.161536, -86.535107),
            new google.maps.LatLng(39.17885, -86.534825),
            new google.maps.LatLng(39.179068, -86.547164),
            new google.maps.LatLng(39.180989, -86.551803),
            new google.maps.LatLng(39.181546, -86.556001),
            new google.maps.LatLng(39.170956, -86.569335),
            new google.maps.LatLng(39.158487, -86.570365),
            new google.maps.LatLng(39.161482, -86.566674),
            new google.maps.LatLng(39.157156, -86.559807),
            new google.maps.LatLng(39.160084, -86.553961),
            new google.maps.LatLng(39.160317, -86.550700),
            new google.maps.LatLng(39.160733, -86.548464),
            new google.maps.LatLng(39.161482, -86.546172),
            new google.maps.LatLng(39.161536, -86.535107)
          ];
          var pv = new google.maps.Polygon(fairview);
        if (google.maps.geometry.poly.containsLocation(myLatlng, pv)) {
            console.log("Location Found in Polygon!!!!! " + myLatlng.lat() + " " + myLatlng.lng());
        } else {
            console.log(":( " + myLatlng.lat() + " " + myLatlng.lng());
        }
```

Comment: I'm not sure if your polygon is correctly initialized. You are not using `google.maps.PolygonOptions`.

Comment: `var pv = new google.maps.Polygon({path:fairview});`

Comment: Okay I see what you are saying now, I'm currently trying your feedback out here, but no luck so far.  http://htinteractive.com/crime_map_fairview2.html

Comment: What did you try? There is still the wrong line `var pv = new google.maps.Polygon(fairview);`

Comment: I'm back now that stackoverflow is up again.  @Dr.Molle if you post your comment back as an answer I'll mark it.  It is working now with that answer.  Thanks for your help.

Comment: [working fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/dJ4Lq/2/)  (based on Dr.Molle's comment)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As Dr. Molle pointed out I was instantiating my polygon incorrectly.

```
var pv = new google.maps.Polygon({path:fairview});
```